# Media Query not working as expected

Tags: css, responsive

I have the follow code.

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 320px) and (max-width : 500px)
```

I have no idea why this rule only works until 480px, This is the following code I'm using to detect the window size.

```
jQuery(window).resize(function (){
  console.clear();
  console.log( jQuery(window).width() );
});
```

The above jQuery is **ONLY USED TO DOUBLE CHECK THE WINDOW**

I have `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`
The issue here is the rule only works until 480px not 500px which it should.

Comment: this might be considering vertical scroll bar as well

Comment: Obvious question but always worth checking - Do you have another media query elesewhere that could be overriding this one, such as `@media (min-width: 480px) {}`. 480px is such a common min-width in `@media` queries as it's the landscape width of iphone 4 I believe?

Comment: No problem, That's actually my first hunch too. I'm working with a ready made template so there should be another mix of media queries. However checking the console my styles are not overwritten but actually not showing. And for example if I change the max-width from 500 to 480 the rule stops working at 460. there's this weird 20px that I can't find where affecting.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `@media only screen and (min-width : 320px) and (max-width : 500px)` with

```
@media all and (min-width : 320px) and (max-width : 500px)
```

> If you use `screen` then it works according to screen sizes.